# Why do servers cache Web pages even though they know the Web page will be changed in the future?

Tags: server, cache, webserver, cache-control, change-management

For performance, some Web pages get cached. This is because the server can then speed up page load time:

```
Without a cached copy

+--SERVER--+                                                   +--CLIENT--+
| [file] --> load file from disk --> read file --> sends over --> loaded  |
+----------+                                                   +----------+

With a cached copy
+--SERVER--+                                             +--CLIENT--+
| [file] --> read file from cache --> sends over network --> loaded |
+----------+                                             +----------+
```

This speeds up the operation.

However, when a file changes, the cache does not change. Even though the cache *can speed up load time* by ***a lot***, the file is still old. The Web site has to regenerate the cache again.

So why do Web servers cache pages even though the file will have to change in the future?

Comment: The answer is speed and/or reducing server load as serving a static/cached page is a lot less cpu intensive then recreating it on demand. That said there are different types of caches/caching mechanisms (eg reverse proxies, wordpress plugins, server directives, cdns) with different focusses- which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the text content on the page changes the cache should store images and CSS that render the page. And while you are on the same page it doesn’t make sense to load the logo over and over.

Comment: What if the *logo* changes *under rare conditions?*

Comment: As long as it takes for logos to get redesigned the cache will expire before then.